# Suppress JavaScript error on page for specific condition

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am getting a javascript error "Invalid argument on Line: 2 Char: 141544 in sp.ui.rte.js" on a SharePoint development. This appears to be a known issue from google within the SharePoint js files - http://wss.boman.biz/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=c0143750-7a4e-4df3-9dba-8a3651407969&ID=69
After analysing the impact I decided that rather than changing the js in the SharePoint 14 hive I want to suppress the error message for just this error. I was trying to do the following:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

            //Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered("Alert"))
            {
                StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();

                cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> window.onerror = function (msg, url, num) {return true;} </");
                cstext1.Append("script>");

                cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", cstext1.ToString());
            }
```

The problem is this will suppress all js errors on the page not just the sp.ui.rte.js ones. Is it possible to do a string search on the URL (http://SHAREPOINT/_layouts/sp.ui.rte.js?rev=uY%2BcHuH6ine5hasQwHX1cw%3D%3D - where the only consistent value between sites will be /_layouts/sp.ui.rte.js? ) to just search and suppress this exact error?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `try`/`catch` block around code in JS. If message matches something you want to ignore, just do nothing. Propagate everything else.

Your original approach with `.onerror` would work too if you change it to analyze message and propagate everything not matching ignored string as well.

Comment: I'd rather not change any of the the SharePoint JS if possible is why I decided not to use the Try/Catch method.I was trying to analyze the message but that is where my problem lies. I saw in one thread someone use urlsearch but I was unable to implement this. Thanks for your input thou!

Answer (score 1):

So far this has been the most successful fix I have found and currently using:

```
function fixRTEBug() {
    // This Fix for parentElement bug in RTE should survive Service Packs and CU's
    function SubstituteRTERangeParentElement() {
        var originalRTERangeParentElement = RTE.Range.prototype.parentElement;
        RTE.Range.prototype.parentElement = function () {
            try {
                originalRTERangeParentElement();
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    }
    SubstituteRTERangeParentElement();
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fixRTEBug, "sp.ui.rte.js");
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` as not defined, so I try to delay that with a `document.ready()` as they say here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31387/error-running-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded?rq=1  but it still doesn't suppress the hierarchy error.  I have more details here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164012/hierarchyrequesterror-in-sp-ui-rte-js